# div opacity outside in other div

Tags: jquery, opacity

I looking-for solution with opacity.
I have div (parent) with another div inside (child).
Parent div has background image with set opacity to 0.5.
Child div is smaller than parent and in his inside see background image with opacity 1.0.
It is possible?

Comment: Ok, I promise to improve. I still thinking is normal forum, but now I know voting is good for other users...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.

If parent div has opacity set, all sub div inherit that opacity.

Comment: Let me know, if you found anything about this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can put the transparency into a background image (a transparent PNG, for instance), or use an RGBA colour to put a flat colour in the background of the parent div - this will only affect the background, without making any text or child elements transparent.

You should be aware that both PNG images and RGBA colours aren't supported 100% across browsers. You may need to put workarounds in place for older browsers if you use these techniques.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using images or have other content in the parent that you need to apply opacity to, you can not have the other div as a child, but instead have it outside the div and absolutely positioned above the other div.

[example](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/)

Comment: This can work, but working this way really messes with the semantic structure of the document. If an effect requires that you break the HTML of your page to achieve it, it's better not to use it.